# printk in driver

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am really new to linux module programming.
I need to some how be able to do some tweak to the ath9k driver in linux.
I finally got the compat wireless source code of ath9k to compile in ubuntu 11.04 and was trying to play around with the code.
I tried using printk to tried to get to see what happen.
First I put printk in the init.c file, the message I printed show up when I use dmesg in the terminal.  However, when I tried to use the same printk in another file like rc.c it does not show up at all.
I am wondering why is that?
And is there some other way that I could some how log some information from the code similar to the fprintf.  What I need is I need to extract somehow the packet header from the driver.

Thank you
Best Regards.

Comment: Strange. Was that part of `rc.c` actually executed? Another question is, which log level do you use in printk? KERN_INFO, KERN_WARNING or whatever else?

Comment: I tried it with KERN_INFO log level.  I put it in quite a few functions in rc.c, but I am not 100% sure if those got run.  I'll try and see if I try printk on another file.  I will also read about the procfs and try it out as Mellowcandle suggested.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

read about the proc fs, it's a great framework to extract data from device drivers.
once you have registered a device node as proc fs, you can read from it.
once the the read function is called, a callback function you defined is creating the output. this is an excellent way to retrieve data from device.

there are also two other methods, one is sysfs, you can google for it. and the second,
if the the device is a char device, you can implement an ioctrl function which returns the info you need.

Comment: I would add that one can also create a file in debugfs and dump the information there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I will look up procfs and then try it out.  Sorry for the late reply.
I'm also not familiar with creating file in debugfs, but I will read on it and try it out.  Thank you very much.